# Why My new flutter apps are created with "subprojects" has already been used in this build script?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my new Flutter app, and I'm stuck on the build gradle file showing : "subprojects" has already been used in this build script [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e015F.jpg)

I've searched on Stack Overflow and Flutter GitHub issues, but I couldn't find a solution that matches my scenario.
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same after syncing gradle files with Android studio. What I did is, I merged them together as shown below and the warning disappeared.

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```